# Array of cards within <Content>

Tags: react-native, native-base

I would like to know if there was any way I could create an array of Card objects using Nativebase, and call upon these objects to change their properties like array[1].Text = "example", although I don't know how I would change the body of an XML tag through a function like the one described above.

Comment: Hey @Abhi Thosar, can please explain the problem a bit more? May be what you trying to achieve? So that I get the context better

Comment: Current state of your question it is hard to understand what you are trying to achieve and what you have tried so far. Please try to give more context to your question and add [mcve] showing what you have tried so far with what problem you have.

Comment: @Subhendu Kundu I'm sorry my question wasn't that clear. Basically what I'm trying to accomplish is to make a schedule with a card for each hour of the day, detailing the event at that time (24 cards each with text inside them). When adding an event, I want to pass a users parameters such as name of event and description to the corresponding time, or card(s). To control which cards the name goes to, based on the time specified, I need to create an array of 24 cards so I can fill specific cards with specific events.

Comment: @bennygenel please read the comment above :)

Comment: these links may be useful http://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#deckswiper-def-headref,
http://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#card-def-headref